# Issues with "&" symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a aspx page from which some strings are passed into the Javascript function. I am facing a strange issue if the string contains a & symbol.

Here is the simplified version of the code

```
if(stringWhichComesFromUI == "AD&D")
{
    //populate a hidden field
    $('#hdnSomeHiddenField').value = "AD&D";
}
```

and in the UI, the hidden field value is populated in a cell inside a grid.

Now the problem is, even if user is sending "AD&D" from the UI, the variable stringWhichComesFromUI is becoming "AD&Amp;D" thats why the if block never executes.

I have also tried with

```
if(stringWhichComesFromUI == "AD&D" || stringWhichComesFromUI == "AD&Amp;D")
{
    //populate a hidden field
    $('#hdnSomeHiddenField').value = "AD&D";
}
```

This executes the if block, but the value which is going into the hidden field does not show properly in the UI. Value which is displayed in UI is "AD", the "&D" part is gone! I am not able to figure out why, please help?

Comment: First of all, `&quot;` isn't `&`. But if your conditions aren't being met according to your expectations, log your `stringWhichComesFromUI`

Comment: `&quot;`? It should be `&amp;`... In any  case, it's an html entity, you just have to decode it first.

Comment: Yes it would be &Amp; sorry I'll edit this

Comment: $('#hdnSomeHiddenField').value ??? you must be wrong, It should be 

`$('#hdnSomeHiddenField').val('AD&D')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error in syntax of assigning value in jquery. Use this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myinput" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="Showme()" Text="Submit" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenFieldText" runat="server" />
```

And your script will be like this:

```
function Showme(){
 var stringWhichComesFromUI= $("#myinput").text();

if(stringWhichComesFromUI == "AD&D")
{
//populate a hidden field
$("#hiddenFieldText").val("AD&D");
}
```

}